# terraform ssh connections fails sometimes

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

terraform ssh connections fails sometimes

Recently,i started learning terraform,
this is my code

```
resource "aws_instance" "myec22" {
  ami = "ami-0c65adc9a5c1b5d7c"
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  key_name = "yet"
  count = 7

  connection {
    type = "ssh"
    user = "ubuntu"
    private_key = file("yet.pem")
    host = self.public_ip
  } 
  vpc_security_group_ids=[ local.sec_id ]
    
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
       some code 
     ]
  }
}
```

sg

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_sg" {
  name = "ec2_sg"

  ingress {
    description = "allow inbiound form secret application "
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 4300
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    protocol = "tcp"
  }

  egress {   
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    protocol = "-1"
  }
}
```

terraform version 1.3.7

when i run the above code it works perfectly fine with 4 out 7 instances rest all gives an error

```
error executing "/tmp/terraform_1050014235.sh": wait: remote command exited without exit status or exit signal
```

Comment: Can you check if you have hit the limit of public IP addresses available for the region?

Comment: nope i don't think so, cause it gave me an error when i ran it the first time. And if i were restart my sandbox it works sometimes. But for some reason if i use ed25519 key type. it isn't giving any error as of now.